# HERE API - Places data - Save/Cache

Tags: here-api

1. Can I save the following information related to a Place?
   Place ID; Title of the place and Lattitude and Longitude of the place?

if so, for how long?

and also can you please let us know if can Cache the data? if so, for how long?

I tried Searching the Policies about the above query but no luck.

Comment: Thank you for your response !!! As per the Here API use policy and based on my understanding we can same the data for 30 days if it improves user experience ( Refer Cache section )   https://legal.here.com/en-gb/terms/acceptable-use-policy and If not, Can we at least save the Place ID indefinitely? similar to google, which let us save the google ID indefinite period of time. We will appreciate your inputs.

Comment: how did you solve your problem? I'm looking to start an app where we need to call the HERE API to get location data and want to be able to tie our user's history back to the locations.

Answer (score 1):

Cache control information can be found in the header cache-control for APIs. Take a reference from Image API at below reference

https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/response-headers.html

Headers :

**cache-control: public,max-age=XXX**

Comment: Thank you for your response !!! As per the Here API use policy and based on my understanding we can same the data for 30 days if it improves user experience ( Refer Cache section ) legal.here.com/en-gb/terms/acceptable-use-policy and If not, Can we at least save the Place ID indefinitely? similar to google, which let us save the google ID indefinite period of time. We will appreciate your inputs. –